# Composer install, "can not scan for class" error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpunit

When executing composer install and I got this error. I am using windows 10, composer version 2.0 and php version 7.4 I've tried deleting the composer.lock file as well as the vender folder and then reinstalling them (multiple times) but that hasn't worked. I have also realized that the backward slashes '' turns into forward slashes '/' after the vendor folder.

Here is the screenshot of the error message:

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVXjq.jpg)

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4.11",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.11",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.7",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.4",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Pictures are not helpful. Copy and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does the folder in question exist?